# Migration to the new hosting not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have developed a site in CodeIgniter, it was working perfectly in my old server as I have changed new server which is in GoDaddy it gives the following error:

> Not Found
>   The requested URL /Foldername/authorise was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Apache Server at "siteurl" Port 80

actually this process coming after login in this site

Thanks in advance

Comment: seems problem with base url..

Comment: Maybe check your mod_rewrite is enabled, and it is stopping your routing working? Other than that, we'd be guessing, as there's so little detail in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to also move the .htaccess ?

It sounds like a rewrite-problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the base_url in the application/config.php as per new server.
Or if there is mod rewrite problem then follow the steps:

1. copy rewrite.load and ssl.load from mods-available to mods-enable.
2. copy default-ssl from sites-available to sites-enable and change as
   From:

Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
allow from all

To:
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
AllowOverride all
Order allow,deny
allow from all

To make .htaccess files work as expected, you need to edit this file:
/etc/apache2/sites-available/default
Look for a section that looks like this:

Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
allow from all

You need to modify the line containing AllowOverride None to read AllowOverride All. This tells Apache that it's okay to allow .htaccess files to over-ride previous directives. You must reload Apache before this change will have an effect:
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload